# Using env with rack_test

Tags: ruby, rspec, rack

In a Rails app, I have the following configuration to run `System` Rspec specs.

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:each, type: :system) do
    driven_by :rack_test
  end

  config.before(:each, type: :system, js: true) do
    driven_by :selenium, using: :headless_chrome, screen_size: [1300, 1240]
  end
end
```

Now, I have added a middleware that depends upon `env['REQUEST_PATH']` and, when I run the specs using `rack_test` I get

> Failure/Error: _, id, request_path = env['REQUEST_PATH'].split('/', 3)
>   NoMethodError: undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass

However, if I always use `selenium`, all the specs pass like before.

Is there a way to use/set `env['REQUEST_PATH']` with `rack_test`?